# giving a unique code by seeing the first column string and the second column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

giving a  unique code by seeing the first column string and the second columns string and whenever the first column string change it starts from 1

Example

[image]

how can I do this using python?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

Let's assume your data is stored in the data frame df

Split the data frame based on unique values in the first column string.

```py
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('colummen1')))

for _, df in dfs.items():
    df['id'] = df.groupby(['colummen1','colummun2']).ngroup()   

dfs = [df[1] for df in dfs]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have got this error when i run it 
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid